# What is an element of a schedule called?

Tags: terminology, modeling, time

I have a question about software modeling terminology, when modeling time.

Say you have a repeating schedule MWF 4-5 p.m.

What do you call Monday 4-5 p.m.? What's the term for that?

```
using System;

namespace myproject.biz
{
  public class ScheduleComponent
  {
    public DayOfWeek DayOfWeek;
    public TimeSpan StartTime;
    public TimeSpan EndTime;
  }
}

namespace myproject.biz
{
  public class Schedule
  {
    public ScheduleComponent[] Components;
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a non-programming-specific question about scheduling.

Comment: @Blrfl, thanks. where can I post this question? This is a term programmers use when modeling time.

Comment: I would call it an *item*; maybe `ScheduleItem` for the class name.

Comment: @5gon12eder, Thanks! I'm looking for the official word as per the giants of architecture. If it doesn't exist, something generic like item or component will have to do.

Comment: _This is a term programmers use when modeling time_ - how can you know that if you don't know what the term is? You're just assuming there is a standard term and that people use it, but this assumption is not obviously well-founded. Anyway, if you're modelling something, the term probably comes from the problem domain (time), and is specific to that domain rather than to programming.

Comment: Do you like the word "event" ? Or "job" ?

Comment: The most common term seems to be 'event'. Google calendar uses that, so does MS Exchange.

Comment: @EngineerDollery, Would you like to create an answer?

Comment: @Useless, because I had used it before but just forgot what it was ;) And, I didn't want to post the question in the time community, simply because time is of the essense, because time is of the essence.

Comment: @Programmer400, it's event.

Comment: At my work, we ended up calling our schedule unit a "schedule occurrence" as we already had another concept called Event.

Comment: See, this is why asking for the "official term" for something is often a pointless exercise.  While it's true that the word "event" is often used with calendar scheduling, it's probably because someone else used it before, who in turn adopted the term from someone else, and now it's just the term that's most commonly used.  But that doesn't make it any more "official" than, say, *"Schedule Record"* or *"Appointment,"* which are arguably better terms. "Event" has too many meanings already; it's a programming language concept, and is arguably more precise in *that* context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are speaking of a fixed time interval allocated in a repetitive schedule, the appropriate term would be **[timeslot](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/timeslot)**.  For example every Monday from 4pm to 5pm. This term is used for example for [broadcasting programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadcast_programming#Time_slot). The definition of your `ScheduleComponent` matches exactly this term.

If you are speaking of a fixed time interval defined in terms of duration, the term would be [time box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeboxing). Example: a weekly sprint, or a 25 minute pomodoro.   But this would correspond neither to your example, nor to your code sample.

If you are speaking of what is to happen at a certain moment in a schedule (focus on what instead of when), you would rather use the terms task, activity or event.

Comment: To support the last paragraph here: Google Calendar and MS Exchange both allow the scheduling of an Event. I don't think that timeslot needs to be repeating, as per the initial assertion. So, an event happens in a timeslot, and it mat be a reoccurring event. To answer properly though we'd need to know more about the domain.